# Double Linked List with smart pointers: problems with insert method

Tags: c++, object-oriented, linked-list, pointers

I'm trying to implement a Templated Double Linked List, following Stroustrup's book "Principles and Practice using C++", Chapter 20.4. Instead of raw pointers, I want to use *unique pointers*.
The code is organized as follows:

- header Node.h where the struct `Node` is implemented: a `unique_pointer` is used for  the next node, and a raw one for the previous
- header Iterator.h where the `Iterator` is implemented
- header List.h where the class `List` is implemented
- a main.cpp where the methods are tested

I've seen that there have been other pretty similar questions, like [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/202333/double-linked-list-using-smart-pointers?rq=1) but **I don't know if the design of my insert method: `iterator insert(iterator p, const T& x)` is okay**. In particular, I obtain a segmentation fault if I call `auto it3 = insert(--p,4)`. Is this okay, or should I fix this?

Here's my Node.h

```cpp
#ifndef Node_h
#define Node_h

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>  // std::unique_ptr
#include <utility> // std::move



namespace Node {


template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
    Node* previous;
    
    Node() noexcept = default;
    explicit Node(const T& _data) : data{_data}, next{nullptr},previous{nullptr} {
        std::cout << "l-value"<<std::endl;
    }
    Node(const T& _data, Node* _next, Node* _previous): data{_data}, next{_next}, previous{_previous} {}

    explicit Node(T&& x) : data{std::move(x)} {
      std::cout << "r-value" << std::endl;
    }
    
    Node(T&& x, Node* _next, Node* _previous) : data{std::move(x)}, next{_next}, previous{_previous} {
      std::cout << "r-value" << std::endl;
    }
    
    explicit Node(const std::unique_ptr<Node> &x) : data{x->data} {
        if (x->next){
        next.reset(new Node{x->next});
        }
//        if (x->previous){
//            previous.reset(new Node{x->previous});
//        }
    }
    
    
    
    ~Node()=default;
    
    //Move semantics, Copy semantics
    
    void printNode(){
        std::cout << "Data is: " << data <<"\n";
    }
    
 };

} //end namespace

#endif /* Node_h */
```

Then, here's the Iterator.h

```cpp
#ifndef Iterator_h
#define Iterator_h

#include "Node.h"
#include <iterator>

template <typename T >
struct __iterator {;
    using NodeT = Node::Node<T>;
    NodeT* current;
    
//public:
    using value_type = T;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using pointer = value_type *;
    
    explicit __iterator(NodeT* p) : current{p} {}
    __iterator() noexcept=default;
    ~__iterator()=default;
    
    reference operator*() const noexcept{
        return current->data;
    }
    
    pointer operator->() const noexcept{
        return &**this;
    }
    
    __iterator& operator++() {
      current = current->next.get();
      return *this;
    }
    
    __iterator& operator--(){
        current=current->previous; //previous is just a raw pointer
        return *this;
    }
    
    
    
    friend bool operator==(__iterator &a, __iterator &b) {
      return a.current == b.current;
    }
    

    friend bool operator!=(__iterator &a, __iterator &b) { return !(a == b); }
};

#endif /* Iterator_h */
```

Here's the header List.h

```cpp
#include "Iterator.h"
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
class List {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Node::Node<T>> first;
    std::unique_ptr<Node::Node<T>> last;
    int _size;
public:
    
    
    using iterator = __iterator<T>;
    
    iterator begin(){return iterator{first.get()};}
    iterator end(){return iterator{nullptr};} //one past the last
    
    iterator go_to(const int n){
        assert(n>=0);
        int i=0;
        if (n < _size) {
            auto tmp{begin()};
            while (i<n) {
                ++tmp;
                ++i;
            }
            return tmp;
        }else{
            return iterator{nullptr};
        }
    }

    List() : first{nullptr}, last{nullptr},_size{0} {}
    ~List() noexcept = default;
    
    
    template <typename O>
    void push_front(O &&x) { // forwarding ref. not r-value

        first.reset(new Node::Node<T>{std::forward<O>(x),first.release(),nullptr});
        if (_size==0) {
            last.reset(nullptr);
        }
        
        ++_size;
    }
    
    template <typename O> //forward reference
    void push_back(O&& x){
        auto tmp = first.get();
        auto _node = new Node::Node<T>{std::forward<O>(x)};
        if (!tmp) {
            first.reset(_node);
            return;
        }

        while (tmp->next) {
            tmp = tmp->next.get();
        }
        tmp->next.reset(_node);
        ++_size;
    }
    
    
    iterator substitute(iterator p, const T& x){
        //_size must not be incremented!
        iterator tmp{p};
        if(tmp.current){
            *tmp = x;
            return tmp;
        }else{
            return iterator{nullptr};
        }

    }
    
    iterator insert(iterator position,const T& value) {
        auto newNode = new Node::Node<T>(value, position.current->next.get(), position.current);
        std::cout << position.current << std::endl;
        if (position.current == last.get() ) {
            last.reset(newNode);
        }
        
        position.current->next.release(); //otherwise: "pointer being freed was not allocated"
        position.current->next.reset(newNode); //set next of previous node to newNode
        ++_size;
        return position;
    }
    

    

    
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, List& l){
        auto itStop = l.end();
        os << "The list has " << l._size << " elements"<<"\n";
        for (auto it = l.begin(); it!=itStop; ++it) {
            os<< *it << " ";
        }
        return os;
    }
    
};
```

Finally, here's the main.cpp file with the tests:

```cpp
#include "List.h"

int main() {

    
    List<int> l{};

    int i=8;
    l.push_front(i); //l-value
    l.push_back(4); //r-value
    l.push_back(i+2); //r-value
    l.push_back(95); //r-value
    l.push_front(29); //l-value
    l.push_front(i*i); //r-value
    std::cout << "My list so far: " << l<<std::endl;

    auto p{l.go_to(3)};
    auto itt = l.substitute(p, 29);
    std::cout << "My list after substitution: \t" << l<<std::endl;

    auto pp{l.go_to(2)};
    auto it2 = l.insert(pp,98);
    std::cout << "My list after insertion: \t" << l<<std::endl;
    auto it3= l.insert(--pp,998);
    std::cout << "My list after insertion: \t" << l<<std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**:

Corrected version of `push_front`:

```
template <typename O>
void push_front(O&& x) {
    auto node = std::make_unique<Node::Node<T>>(std::forward<O>(x));
    std::swap(node, first);  
    first->next = std::move(node);
    if (_size == 0) {
        assert(!last);
        assert(!first->next);
        last = first.get();
    }else{
first->next->previous = first.get()
}
    ++_size;
}
```

Comment: @AryanParekh This is working. The fact is that I don't know if the design should be compatible with a call like tho one I mentioned in the question

Comment: Alright then, my bad. It sounded like that to me when i read it

Comment: @AryanParekh no worries !

Comment: Also, why are you beginning your names with `__`? They are [reserved identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: I wrote like that because it was the name of my `Iterator` class. Thanks for this suggestion, gonna fix this! @AryanParekh

Comment: Also, in the linked answer (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/202333/double-linked-list-using-smart-pointers?rq=1) I've just seen that in his iterator, when he implements the operator `--`, the OP wrote `node = node->previous.get()` which should be wrong because `previous` was declared as a raw pointer, like I did. The fact is that in this way such a statement like `insert(--p,4)` would not work, right @AryanParekh?

Comment: Please refrain from fundamentally changing the question, especially after receiving answers.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm sorry. you're right. Thanks for re-editing everything back :-)

Answer (score 6):

You have a number of problems with memory management in this linked list. The key thing to remember is that `unique_ptr` indicates ownership of an object. Use of `release`, `reset`, and to a lesser extent `get` are a code smell: not always wrong, but often an indication that the class is being used incorrectly. Usually you should use `swap` and move-assignment instead. I'll call these out as I work through the files.

A quick note: I have not tested or even compiled the following code; it may contain some errors.

### Node.h

This is mostly fine. The "copy" constructor (`Node(std::unique_ptr<Node>&)`) probably should just be removed. It doesn't really make sense to copy a node and all its descendants. Even if you wanted that behavior, this implementation is buggy. It removes all the previous links, so that you've got a singly linked list that pretends to be a double linked list.

### Iterator.h

Your iterator class is not quite right. It doesn't work as an `end` iterator. In particular, `--l.end()` exhibits undefined behavior because it dereferences a null pointer. In practice, iterator classes tend to need a reference to the collection that they come from.

In addition, this iterator does not meet the requirements of a [bidirectional iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) (I know you mark this as a forward iterator, but it also does not meet those requirements). In particular, it violates:

- "lvalues of type It satisfy Swappable"; I'm a little rusty here but I'm pretty sure your user-declared destructor prevents the implicitly declared move constructor and move assignment operator from being generated; you must either provide those functions (e.g. using `= default`) or a `swap` function.
- It does not support the postfix increment and decrement operators.

### List.h

`List::last` isn't really implemented correctly. As far as I can make out, it's never actually set to anything other than `nullptr` by the code as is. In any case, this should *not* be a `unique_ptr`, because anything it points to is already owned by another `unique_ptr`.

So let's change `last` to a `Node::Node<T>*`. We have the following invariants that are true before and after each member function exits: If `_size == 0`, `first==last==nullptr`. Otherwise,

- `first` points to the first node in the list
- `first->previous == nullptr`
- Given a reachable node `n`, `n->next` is null or `n->next.get() == n->next->previous`
- `last` points to the last reachable node in the list. `last.next` is null.
- `_size` nodes are reachable.

We need to write our member functions so that these invariants remain true.

`go_to` would usually be achieved through applying [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) to the begin iterator. That has a difference of behavior when you're trying to go past the end of the list; using `std::next` would result in undefined behavior in that case. If you want the current behavior you could implement it with something like

```
iterator go_to(const int n) const {
    if (n >= _size) {
        return end();
    } else {
        return std::next(begin(), n);
    }
}
```

When you're using `unique_ptr` to manage memory, you should generally not use `new`. Instead, use `std::make_unique` if you're using C++14 or later (and write your own `make_unique` in C++11). This allows you to improve the exception safety of your code. Try this for `push_front`:

```
template <typename O>
void push_front(O&& x) {
    auto node = std::make_unique<Node::Node<T>>(std::forward<O>(x));
    swap(node, first);  // assuming you implement swap or add a "using std::swap;" on the previous line
    first->next = std::move(node);
    if (_size == 0) {
        assert(!last);
        assert(!first->next);
        last = first.get();
    }
    ++_size;
}
```

Here, node is created in an exception-safe manner. There is no chance of leaking `first`, since we do not release it (your code would leak `first` if the allocation failed or if `Node`'s constructor threw (due to `T`'s move constructor throwing)). Assuming your `swap` and `move` are no-throw operations, either `push_front` succeeds, and
the new element has been inserted at the beginning, or the allocation fails, `push_front` throws, and the data structure has not been changed.

As for `push_back`, if you're not using `last` here, there's no reason to have `last` at all.

```
template <typename O>
void push_back(O&& x) {
    auto node = std::make_unique<Node::Node<T>>(std::forward<O>(x));
    if (_size == 0) {
        assert(!last);
        assert(!first);
        first = std::move(node);
        last = node.get();
        _size = 1;
        return;
    }
    assert(!last->next);
    node->previous = last;
    last->next = std::move(node);
    last = last->next.get();
    ++_size;
}
```

Again, we ensure that the class's invariants hold, even if we throw while constructing the new node.

I don't think `substitute` is a reasonable function. Your list's user should write `*it = x;` and they should know whether their iterator is valid or not.

The normal semantics for `insert` are to insert a value just *before* the iterator passed in, not just after. This allows `insert` to insert at any position in the list and it means that `insert` has sensible semantics when `end()` is passed as the iterator.

```
iterator insert(iterator it, const T& value) {
    auto node = std::make_unique<Node::Node<T>>(value);
    auto prev = it.current ? it.current->previous : last;
    auto ptr = prev ? &first : &prev->next;
    swap(*ptr, node);
    (*ptr)->next = std::move(node);
    (*ptr)->previous = prev;
    ++_size;
    if (!last) last = first.get();
    return iterator(ptr->get());
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and for all your suggestions: I tried to fix as much as I could, but the your insertion now is puzzling me: it seems to me that you're inserting always at the begin of the list. Indeed, this is what happens if I run my main.cpp (see EDIT). 

Also, it happens that for some value of the iterator `it`I got that `auto prev` is nullptr and hence when I call `std::move` I got segmentation fault. Honestly, I can't understand where's the problem @ruds

Comment: I updated my EDIT with the actual problem: I think there must be a bug in the insertion now, because sometimes it does not work, and when it works it adds the element at the begin of the list

Comment: Apologies. My assignment to ptr is backwards. It should be `auto ptr = prev ? &prev->next : first;`

Comment: Thanks so much, but there's still a problem with your fix: let's say that I fill my empy list i`l` in this way:  `l.push_front(8)`, `l.push_back(4)`, `l.push_back(10)`, `l.push_back(7)`, `l.push_front(9)`, `l.push_back(5)` (note that `9` has been `push_front`ed).

Comment: If now I want to insert an element between the first and the second, it happens that the in the `insert` method `it.current->previous` is equal to `nullptr` and hence the element will be placed at the begin. This is due to the `push_front`: the node after the one you just pushed has no `previous` referring to the new inserted one: in this case, the Node  `7` doesn't have `previous` pointing to Node `9`
 I think that your design of `insert` should also support this case, right? @ruds

Comment: `l.insert(l.begin(), 42)` will insert 42 as the new first element of the list. `l.insert(++l.begin(), 42)` will insert it as the new second element.

Comment: `l.insert(++l.begin(), 42)` is still inserting it as first element. This is due to the fact that `position.current->previous` is still `nullptr` and hence `auto ptr` is equal to `&first`. I can't understand how to fix this fact. What am I missing? @ruds

Comment: Ah, I see there is a bug in my `push_front`. It does not set `first->next->previous = first.get();`

Comment: One way to catch these issues during development is to write a function that checks the class invariants, and to call that function on entry to every member function, and again just before returning.

Comment: I got it to work with a slightly modification of your `push_front` I wrote at the and of my original answer (basically I just wrote an `else`). Did you mean to fix it in that way? It works now. If you could confirm it's right, you'll saved my day :-) @ruds

Comment: Yes, that looks right

Answer (score 3):

## Move `class Node` and `struct __iterator` into `class List`

It is very weird to see `Node::Node<T>` inside the code. A `Node` is an implementation detail of your `List`, so it should be declared inside `class List`. The same goes for `__iterator`. For example:

```
template<typename T>
class List {
    class Node {
        T data;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
        Node *previous;
    };
    
    std::unique_ptr<Node> first;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> last;
    ...

public:
    class iterator {
         Node *current;

    public:
         using value_type = T;
         ...
    };

    iterator begin() {...};
    ...
};
```

Notice how all this avoids needing to introduce `namespace`s or `__` prefixes ([which you should avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)) to hide them, and how this reduces the number of times you have to explicitly write `<T>`. Of course, now everything has to be declared inside `List.h`, but I don't see that as a drawback.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should follow C++ standard `insert` for containers by passing a `begin` and `end` iterator, for example

```
template<typename T>
void insert(Iterator begin, Iterator begin2, Iterator end2);
void insert(Iterator begin, T value);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But in this case the method is designed so that `iterator(iterator p,T value)` returns an iterator and inserts the value `x` in the list right after `p`. My bigger problem is that if I do something like `insert(--p,4)`, for instance, I got segmentation fault.